# How to stop JDialog from hiding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have the below class:

```
 public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
 {
   ..
 }
```

Which holds JDialog with one button component. The Dialog works, but hides when I press the button.
Do anyone knows how to stop the dialog from hiding?

Answer (score 0):

The routine the button executes must be firing the dialog dispose call. 
See if you can find `dispose();` and comment it out.

Comment: You can save time by posting the routine under your action event, calld by your button. I suspect somewhere along the line a parent is calling dispose against the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call setCancelable(false) on your objetc?

Would be better if you post more code.